# Selecting multiple rows from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table structure:

```
- table users -
user_id
user_name

- table groups -
group_id
group_name

- table group_members -
group_id
user_id
```

Let's also say I have this in the DB:

```
users:
1:administrator

groups:
1:administrators
2:superusers
3:normal users

group_members:
1:1 (user_id 1 is member of group_id 1)
1:2
1:3
```

Now, how do I go efficient with selecting all users, and with that, the groups they're member of? Do I have to execute 3 queries selecting all rows from all 3 tables, and fetch it with arrays in PHP, or is there a more effecient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.*, g.group_name
from users u
inner join group_members gm on gm.user_id = u.user_id
inner join groups g on g.group_id = gm.group_id
where u.user_id = 123
```

Comment: This shows me just one user, and if I remove the where and fix the typo's, it only shows the FIRST group they're member of, while I want to get __all__ the groups they're member of.

Comment: The query looks correct. I think you have wrong data. The table group_members as you specified it has group_id and then user_id. so according to the data you supplied it means group 1 has three users 1,2 and 3. check your group_members table content and make sure 1, 2, 3 are in the group column and not in the user column. Also, this query lists only users that have at least one relation in the table group_members. if you want all users including those that have no groups, replace the word "inner" with the word "left" in both places in the query.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work if there are no null fields in group and group_members table

if there are null fields replace inner join with left join

```
select users.username, group.group_name
from users  
inner join group_members on group_members.user_id = users.user_id
inner join groups  on group.group_id = group_members.group_id
```